# Attaching SpriteNodes in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game that involves a knight with a shield swiveling on a fixed point.  The shield and the knight must have different physics bodies so they can interact with projectiles differently.  I am looking for a way to attach the shield to the knight so that they will swivel together, with the knight acting as the center point.  I have tried adding the shield to the knight as a child, but this changes the center swiveling point to somewhere between them, causing the knight to be off center.

```
        var knight = SKSpriteNode()
        var shield = SKSpriteNode()        

        // KNIGHT

        var knightSkin = SKTexture(imageNamed: "PlaceholderKnight.png")

        knight = SKSpriteNode(texture: knightSkin)
        let knightResize = SKAction.scaleBy(0.6, duration: 0.0)
        knight.runAction(knightResize)
        knight.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        knight.zPosition = 100

        let knightSize = CGSizeMake(knight.frame.size.width, knight.frame.size.height)
        knight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: knightSize)

        self.addChild(knight)

        // SHIELD

        var shieldSkin = SKTexture(imageNamed: "PlaceholderShield.png")

        shield = SKSpriteNode(texture: shieldSkin)
        shield.zPosition = 100

        let shieldSize = CGSizeMake(shield.frame.size.width, shield.frame.size.height)
        shield.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: shieldSize)

        knight.addChild(shield)
```

Comment: You will need to adjust the actor point of the shield.

Comment: @EpicByte anchor point

Comment: @0x141E Oops good catch, can't edit my comment though :|

Answer (score 1):

You want an `SKPhysicsJoint`. There are a number of types of physics joints, and they all allow physics bodies to interact together, move together, etc. For instance, a pin will allow two physics bodies to rotate around a central fixed point.

[Apple Develop Page: SKPhysicsJoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJoint_Ref/index.html)

[SKPhysicsJointPin Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542867/3708223)

Comment: I don't want them to rotate around a central point.  I want the knight to be the center.  The shield will just be "attached" to him.  Can I use SKPhysicsJointFixed for this?  I was messing around with that earlier but wasn't having much luck.

Comment: Yeah, a fixed joint means they just move together as though they were one physics body. I just linked the Pin example since I don't know you're specific needs. But you certainly need a physics joint to have two physics bodies move together.

Comment: Thank you.  I will give that another go.